# How do you transform Adjacency matrices to Incidence matrices and vice-versa?

Tags: c++, math, graph

Let's say the matrices are the following:
(N = 4)

Adjacency:

0110
1001
1001
0110

Incidence:

1100
1010
0101
0011

How can you get the Incidence matrix from having just the Adjacency one, and vice-versa?

P.S: The Adjacency Matrix I'm getting from a .txt document, which I've read into an array and got it by the following algorithm:

```
int read(){

    ifstream graf("graf.txt");
    if(graf.is_open()){
        graf >> n;
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<2; j++)
                graf >> Graf[i][j];
        }
    }
    graf.close();
    return 0;
}

void adj() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        sz[i][j] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {sz[Graf[i][j]-1][Graf[i][j+1]-1] = 1;}
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        sz[j][i] = sz[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Presumably this is a mathematics question, not specific to C++.

Comment: It certainly is, just failed to add that as a tag :) ** Added it now, thanks for the pointer(s) !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a math problem. Let's move this to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thing is it doesn't let me post it there, it requires me to have 1000 RP in order to add the "graph" tag, which I don't have.

Comment: @Shadpwness Ah well, it is actually better suited at mathoverflow.net. Just use the graph-theory tag there.

Comment: @stefan: same thing, this one requires only 300 RP tho :D

Comment: @Shadpwness well then just leave out the tag..

Comment: Thanks, posted it there as well :)

Comment: Then wait until you have enough rep, instead of trying to bypass the restrictions by posting your problem in the wrong place or under the wrong tag. Thanks. Also boo to cross-posting.

Comment: I didn't try to bypass any restriction, just that they were named otherwise which I haven't notice. The question got marked as off-topic on mathoverflow.net, so I guess it still remains a programming question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Really? Are we nitpicking about where to post this, and once it's posted somewhere else, complaining about cross posting? Could have just edited the question to be tagged `math` and `algorithm` and then actually helped.

Comment: Check this > [C program to convert adjacency matrix to Incidence matrix](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/wap-to-convert-adjacent-matrix-to.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn an adjacency matrix into an incidence matrix by looking at every possible connection between vertices and whenever there is indeed a connection, add an edge to your incidence matrix. Be careful to look at each combination of vertices only once, though.

The other way around, you can simply look at each edge. The incidence matrix specifies for each edge, which two vertices it connects.

The one situation you cannot recreate is when more than a single edge connects the same two vertices.

Here's some source code to illustrate the above explanations ([See it work](http://ideone.com/9S974t)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<bool> matrix_row;
typedef std::vector<matrix_row> matrix; // Saves some typing

// The initially given matrix. Uses C++11 initializer list.
matrix adj = 
{
    { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 1, 0 }
};

matrix adjacency_to_incidence(const matrix &adj)
{
    int cols = adj.size();
    assert(cols > 0);

    int rows = adj[0].size();
    assert(rows > 0);

    assert(rows == cols);

    int edge = 0;
    matrix incidence;

    for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
        // We only look at half the adjacency matrix, so that we only add each
        // edge to the incidence matrix once.
        for (int row = 0; row <= col; ++row) {
            if (adj[col][row]) {
                incidence.push_back(matrix_row(cols, 0));
                incidence[edge][row] = incidence[edge][col] = 1;
                ++edge;
            }
        }
    }

    return incidence;
}

matrix incidence_to_adjacency(const matrix &inc)
{
    int edges = inc.size();
    assert(edges > 0);

    int vertices = inc[0].size();
    assert(vertices > 0);

    matrix adjacency(vertices, matrix_row(vertices, 0));

    for (int edge = 0; edge < edges; ++edge) {
        int a = -1, b = -1, vertex = 0;
        for (; vertex < vertices && a == -1; ++vertex) {
            if (inc[edge][vertex]) a = vertex;
        }
        for (; vertex < vertices && b == -1; ++vertex) {
            if (inc[edge][vertex]) b = vertex;
        }
        if (b == -1) b = a;
        adjacency[a][b] = adjacency[b][a] = 1;
    }

    return adjacency;
}

void print_matrix(const matrix &m)
{
    int cols = m.size();
    if (cols == 0) return;
    int rows = m[0].size();
    if (rows == 0) return;

    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            std::cout << m[c][r] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    matrix incidence = adjacency_to_incidence(adj);
    print_matrix(incidence);

    matrix adjacency = incidence_to_adjacency(incidence);
    print_matrix(adjacency);

    return 0;
}
```

When your graph is large, it might be worth considering running the loop in `adjacency_to_incidence` twice. The first time to count the amount of edges, then initialize the matrix with enough space and then loop over the adjacency matrix again to populate the incidence matrix.