# How to transform Adjacency matrix to Incidence matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, graph

Let the matrix have 4 verticles and 4 edge: (1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4). I need to fill  Adjacency (I did) and transform this Adjacency matrix to Incidence matrix. The result should be a matrix `Incidence={(0111),(1010),(1101),(1010)}` What is the best algorithm. I can't find a solution, all ideas are with bugs. :-( Thanks

[image: matrices]

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Rebro {
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
};


int main()
{
    int Graph[100][100], Vertex, Edge, x, y;
    int VG, EG;
    int Incidence[100][100];
    cout << "Enter number of vertexes:";
    cin >> Vertex;
    cout << "\nEnter number of edges:";
    cin >> Edge;
    //_________________________NULL
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            Graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //_________________________NULL
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            Incidence[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //_________________________INPUT
    Rebro mass[100];
    cout << "\nEnter edges:\n " << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Edge; i++)
    {
        cout << "e1=";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "e2=";
        cin >> y;
        cout << endl;
        Graph[x][y] = 1;
        Graph[y][x] = 1;

        mass[i].x =x ;
        mass[i].y =y ;
    }
    //_________________________OUTPUT
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            cout <<"  "<< Graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Edge; i++) {

        Incidence[i][mass[i].x] = 1;
        Incidence[i][mass[i].y] = 1;
    }
    //_________________________OUTPUT
    cout << "\nIncidence matrix:\n" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        {
            cout << "  " << Incidence[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

[image: result]

OR generally a wrong idea:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Graph[100][100], Vertex, Edge, x, y;
    int VG, EG;
    int Incidence[100][100];
    cout << "Enter number of vertexes:";
    cin >> Vertex;
    cout << "\nEnter number of edges:";
    cin >> Edge;
    //_________________________NULL
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            Graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //_________________________NULL
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            Incidence[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //_________________________INPUT
    cout << "\nEnter edges:\n " << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Edge; i++)
    {
        cout << "e1=";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "e2=";
        cin >> y;
        cout << endl;
        Graph[x][y] = 1;
        Graph[y][x] = 1;
    }
    //_________________________OUTPUT
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
        {
            cout <<"  "<< Graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
 for (int i =1; i<=Edge; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=Edge; j++) {
            if (Graph[x][y]==1) {
                if ((i==x)||(i==y)||(j==x)||(j==y)) {
                    Incidence[i][j]==1;
                    Incidence[j][i]==1;
                }
                else {
                    Incidence[i][j]==0;
                    Incidence[j][i]==0;
                }
        }
    }
 }
    //_________________________OUTPUT
    cout << "\nIncidence matrix:\n" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= Vertex; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= Vertex; i++)
        {
            cout << "  " << Incidence[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: appreciate the effort that you took to present your ideas as well in code.

Comment: sorry i'm new here

Comment: I see that you use always [1 ... N] (N inclusively). So, it may work assuming sufficient extra space in arrays. Though, it still feels very unnatural for a C++ developer... ;-)

Comment: Btw. your exposed code is close to a proper [mcve] if you drop `#include "conio.h"`, `#include <stdlib.h>` (needed for what?), and the unnecessary `_getch()` at the end. (With these modifications, I was able to run your code on [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81322bf07752643d).)

Comment: I digged a while through your code, made a clean-up here and there, without seeing anything. Finally, I got it: You simply made an INPUT error (and I didn't notice when a copied from your snapshot). So, you input `2 3` for the third edge, and `2 4` for the fourth edge BUT: the third edge (c) is `2 4` and the fourth edge (d) is `2 3`. Fixing this in my [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4159cdc17de1e02), I immediately got the expected results. :-)

Comment: This is not that seldom, due to my experience (from ca. 25 years in business): You're desperately searching a bug which you cannot find until you notice that you search at the fully wrong location. (And, the bug was actually a stupid simple...) :-)

Comment: Btw. what I noticed: The last nested loops for output of `Incidence` contained a bug (which didn't become effective because in your example `Edge` == `Vertex`): The inner loop should be `for (int i = 1; i <= Edge; i++)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Scheff Ohh, yeah, you're right, it should, I have already fixed it. It's really stupid simple. I need to be more attentive. I still don't know C ++ well, but we have already been given the opportunity to form algorithms for the graph, it's difficult. Thank you.

Comment: See the answer in this link: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380139/how-do-you-transform-adjacency-matrices-to-incidence-matrices-and-vice-versa>.